# Hopf algebras and bijective antipodes

Tags: hopf-algebras

By a theorem of Larson and Sweedler, the antipode of every finite-dimensional Hopf algebra is bijective.
My question is the following:

Is it true that in every noetherian Hopf algebra the antipode is bijective?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is conjectured that the antipode is bijective for all noetherian Hopf algebras (Skryabin), but no proof is known. Take a look at this recent short survey, ["Noetherian Hopf Algebras"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.4854), by K.R. Goodearl, where this is listed as conjecture 1.9. Skryabin's original paper is:

> S. Skryabin, [New results on the bijectivity of antipode of a Hopf algebra](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869306002328), J. Algebra 306
>   (2006), 622–633